# Php Wordpress Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, html-lists, gallery

i'm trying to get a slider to feature my images that are in a post. I currently have everything set up but I only have one li element that is showing all three images. I'd love to have three li elements each showing one image but I can't figure out how to automatically isolate each image. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

you can see the current state here:
http://mksgear.com/shop/test-product/

this is what my code looks like:

```
<ul class="slides">

  <li class="slide">

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery option1="value1"]'); ?>


<?php else : ?>

    <img src="<?php echo woocommerce_placeholder_img_src(); ?>" alt="Placeholder" />

<?php endif; ?>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what plugin are you using? have you looked through the options?

Comment: I'm using the "Advanced Slider" plugin and I don't see any options where you can insert a post's gallery within a slide automatically. I want the customer to be able to add images to the gallery and then have the gallery populate the slideshow that is coded onto the post's page

Comment: If you want a different gallery for each post, you can use the `Images` menu and add the images as attachments to the post.

Comment: correct, and then how would I get the images to show up as slides? http://mksgear.com/shop/test-product/ is where I'm at currently: one slide (because it is in one li element) and the [gallery] shows all three images at once.

Comment: if you forego using the plugin, you can write your own code for a slide or (better) use a jquery slide (there are hundreds). All you have to do is make a query for all the attachments related to the post, and pull them in the loop with whatever template you want

Comment: Thanks for your help, so is there no way I can easily change my existing code above to do what you're talking about?

Comment: when it comes to wordpress plugins they sometimes tend to be somewhat restricting since they impose their own structure (even when some customization is offered out of the box). So it is sometimes better to leave control to yourself, which enables you to tailor the site to your client's needs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I'll give an answer a go.  If I have misunderstood what you're trying to do please clarify it for me and I'll update my answer.

You can use `itemtag="li"` inside the gallery shortcode to wrap each image in an `li`.  You'd need to remove your `<li class="slide">` line of code, and maybe use jQuery to add the "slide" class back to the generated `li` tags.  So you could do something like this:

Also, does your code render the gallery when using the `:` in the if/else statement?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#slides li").addClass("slide");
});
</script>

<ul class="slides">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery itemtag="li" option1="value1"]'); ?>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <img src="<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/thumbnail-default.jpg" />

    <?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Add this you your footer, you can add it inside the same document.ready as the jQuery to add the class slide.  Just copy and paste this on a new line right after `jQuery("slides li").addClass("slide");`.  You can adjust the height, width, or any other options in this call if you need to.  This will hopefully work.

```
jQuery("#slides").advancedSlider({
width: 900, 
height: 460, 
responsive: 1, 
skin: 'light-round'
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AndyWarren, not sure where I should be putting the jquery at the top? I feel like this is definitely going toward what I'm looking to do though!

Comment: You can put that piece of jQuery inside your `<head></head>` tags which is in the header.php file.  You could also put it in your footer.php right before the closing `</body>` tag.  Just make sure to include the full document.ready statement too, and enclose it all inside of some `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Oh, and also wrap your placeholder image in `<li></li>` tags, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Thanks again! They error is gone but the slide still isn't showing up on this page, anything else I can give you to help me troubleshoot? I really appreciate it! http://mksgear.com/shop/test-product-accessories/

Comment: Firebug says jQuery is not defined on that page you just linked.

Comment: I've added this both in the header.php in between <head></head> and also in the footer.php right above the </body> tag, is this what I was supposed to do?                           <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("slides li").addClass("slide");
});
</script>

Comment: You also have `#slider-pro-1` as the id for the jquery plugin to look for.  The code you posted above is using the id of `slides`.  Only add the jquery snippet I posted once, in the header or footer, but not both.

Comment: I think you're if/else statement is written incorrectly maybe.  I'll post a new snippet above in my answer.

Comment: Try the new if/else statement in my answer.

Comment: I've updated the code and nothing changed, I added <li></li> and still nothing changed. :/ I'm sorry, anything else we can try? Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Its a bit tough without seeing your PHP files.  Try adding just this `<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery itemtag="li" option1="value1"]'); ?>` where you want the slider to render to see if the gallery is even rendering when outside of the if/else statement.

Comment: Also, does the post have a featured image set?  That is what the if statement is checking for.

Comment: I've done this and it looks like the <li> is trying to show up (you can see a bullet)... does this help at all? And yes, there are 3 images in the featured image set.

Comment: I seen that too.  Are you sure the post/page has images in its gallery?  It looks like an empty gallery.  Again, its hard to tell without logging into your WP or seeing your template files.  Make sure the post has images uploaded to its gallery.

Comment: There can't be 3 images that are "Featured Images" unless you're using a plugin like Multiple Post Thumbnails.  There should only be one Featured image per post without the additional plugin.

Comment: Sweet! I deleted and re-uploaded some test images and they are now showing up!

Comment: Great, now wrap gallery shortcode back into the if/else statement and make sure the post has one of the images set as its "Featured Image".

Comment: Also, I added your code from above, check out where we're at! http://mksgear.com/shop/test-product-accessories/

Comment: You also need to make a call to the plugin with the correct id of `slides`  The piece of jQuery I gave you needs to be moved to the footer before the closing `</body>` tag also to eliminate the "jquery is not defined error".

Comment: When viewing your source, there are several script file links that do not go to the file.  I think you have some incorrect paths.  I have to jet, but I'll check this again in a couple hours to see where you're at with it.  If my answers help you get it corrected please give me an upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Also this code `<div class="advanced-slider" id="mixed-slider">  
<ul class="slides">  
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>  
<li class="slides"><?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery itemtag="li"]'); ?></li>  
  <?php } else { ?>
  <img src="<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/thumbnail-default.jpg" />
<?php } ?>  
</ul>  
</div>  ` is now making the "decription" and "review" css style stop working, any ideas how to get that working again? http://mksgear.com/shop/test-product-accessories/

Comment: and would it be easiest to take the slider code from the homepage and just insert the code to pull the images? So the styling would all be the same? Can it work like that? It sounds too good to be true..

Comment: You need to fire the plugin for the new slider on that accessories page.  I don't see it being fired in the source.  Check my answer above, I'll add some new code to the bottom of it.

Comment: Made the updates but it doesn't seem to be helping... did I miss something?

Comment: Noticed one more thing.  In this line: `jQuery("slides li").addClass("slide");` there needs to be a `#` right before slides.  So it should be `jQuery("#slides li").addClass("slide");`.  Also, in the call to the plugin it should be `#slides` rather than `#slider`.  It look like I missed that when writing the code.

Comment: I wish I could help more, but without having access to the files and WP backend it makes troubleshooting more difficult.  If you'd like me to take a look at it and get it going you can view my profile on here and find my website URL.  There's a form on there where you can send me FTP and login creds.  Aside from getting into the theme/plugin code I don't think there's much more I can do.